# typed actors vs futures - how are they different?

Tags: scala, akka, future, typedactor

I am reading about [typed actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/typed-actors.html) and the interface a typed actor provides looks like this :

```
trait Squarer {
  def squareDontCare(i: Int): Unit //fire-forget

  def square(i: Int): Future[Int] //non-blocking send-request-reply

  def squareNowPlease(i: Int): Option[Int] //blocking send-request-reply

  def squareNow(i: Int): Int //blocking send-request-reply

  @throws(classOf[Exception]) //declare it or you will get an UndeclaredThrowableException
  def squareTry(i: Int): Int //blocking send-request-reply with possible exception
}
```

How is this different from a simple Future ?

They really seem similar, the interface is the same for `def square(i: Int): Future[Int]`.

Is it so that typed actors are location transparent (and can be run on other nodes) but Futures are not ?

So typed actors can be thought of as a sort of more restricted form of Futures? In the sense that the Future construction is restricted such that for future construction nothing can be used that cannot come through a wire (not serializable). For example closures (or any function) cannot be passed to typed actors but can be used for constructing Futures.

Comment: Typed Actors: "This module will be deprecated as it will be superseded by the Akka Typed project which is currently being developed in open preview mode."

"Typed actors are nice for bridging between actor systems (the “inside”) and non-actor code (the “outside”), because they allow you to write normal OO-looking code on the outside."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the following usecase: suppose your service behind the actor has a mutable state. Since method call is a message and messages are processed sequentially you get synchronisation of service's internal state.

BTW actors by default don't restrict messages to be serializable.

Comment: Good point ! Thanks. Thats a pretty big differences indeed. Futures are "execute once", ephemeral so to speak, while actors have a longer life.